# error using EnvelopedSignature.open (error msg: "output cipher initiation failed")

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I implement encryption of the message using the EnvelopedSignature class.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream envelopedByteArrayOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
EnvelopedSignature signature = new EnvelopedSignature ();
if (cert != null) {
    signature.addKeyAgreeRecipient ((X509Certificate) cert);
    // or signature.addKeyTransRecipient ((X509Certificate) cert);
} else {
    throw new Exception ("Certificate error.");
}
signature.open (envelopedByteArrayOutStream);
signature.update (inData, 0, inData.length);
signature.close ();
```

I receive an error "output cipher initiation failed" in the 
`signature.open (envelopedByteArrayOutStream);`
Help to understand the error.

P.S. the change of rights did not help for me(https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

Thanks.